# Spring Boot Image upload error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload, image-uploading

Keep getting `Required request part 'file' is not present` when uploading an image into a controller (all other services work fine). I have ruled out Postman by successfully uploading to this [spring-guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files). Not sure what is missing.

**Spring Could Version**: 
Edgware.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{account_id}/image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity uploadProfileImage(
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
    @PathVariable String account_id) {
    ...
}
```

**Postman:**
[image]
[image]

**Dependencies from POM**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the header name `Content-Type` with `multipart/form-data` as value?

Comment: Yup. No effect. According to some posts adding Content Type might make things even worse. Also, checking the Postman's console showed that it did add the Content Type properly.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it on my end, the only way I can get the same error message is if I try to use a key other than 'file'. I'll keep looking, though

Comment: What's the error message when you change `@RequestParam("file")` to `@RequestParam("potato")`? It should be `Required request part 'potato' is not present`, but if it's not, it means that another endpoint is intercept the request.

Comment: can you try with `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file` once .This is an working example of file upload https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=3&postId=1295

Comment: @TwiN "Required request part 'potato' is not present"

Comment: @ArpanDas Same error. I have at least a couple of other functioning upload projects which work fine. The problem is that none of those have the exact same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this particular configuration was to move the project from Edgeware with Spring Boot 1.5.13 to Finchley with Spring Boot 2.0.1.